# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState.list is undefined

Tags: javascript, react, crud

Estou fazendo um projeto do tipo `CRUD` com o `React` e ao compilar apareceu isso:

> `"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState.list is undefined"`

```
export default class UserCrud extends Component {

    state = { ...initialState}

    clear ()  {
        this.setState({user: initialState.user})
    }

    save () {
        const user = this.state.user
        const method = user.id ? 'put' : 'post'
        const url = user.id ? `${baseUrl}/${user.id}` : baseUrl //outro erro
        axios[method] (url, user)
        .then(resp => {
            const list = this.getUpdateList(resp.data)
            this.setState({user: initialState.user, list})
        })
        
    }

    getUpdateList  (user) { // onde está o erro
        const list = this.setState.list.filter(u => u.id !== user.id)
        list.unshift(user)
        return list
    }

    updateField (event)  {
        const user = { ...this.state.user}
        user[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        this.setState({user})
    }
```

Comment: `initialState` o que é isso? isso não existe: `const list = this.setState.list.filter(u => u.id !== user.id)` e eu acho pura suposição que é `const list = this.state.list.filter(u => u.id !== user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Para responder essa pergunta precisamos entrender o que é o state e o setState do React.

### State

É uma propriedade da instância da classe do seu componente, a doc do React define state como sendo:

> O state contém dados específicos a este componente que podem mudar com o tempo. O state é definido pelo usuário e deve ser um objeto JavaScript.
>
> Se algum valor não for usado para renderizamento ou para controle de
> data flow (por exemplo, um ID de timer), você não precisa colocar no
> state. Tais valores podem ser definidos como campos na instância do
> componente.

E uma coisa importante que a documentação fala é:

> Nunca mude this.state diretamente, pois chamar setState() após a mutação pode substituir a mutação realizada. Trate this.state como se ele fosse imutável.

Ou seja, o state é como se fosse uma "variável reativa" que você tem, que contém um objeto, no qual você pode armazenar valores que ao serem modificados, terão efeitos na interface.

### SetState

Como a própria documentação do state avisa, você nunca deve fazer uma atribuição direta ao state com `this.state = {chave: valor}` por exemplo, para alterar o valor de um state você sempre deve utilizar a função setState.

### O problema descrito

Nesta linha:

> const list = this.setState.list.filter(u => u.id !== user.id)

O que você aparentemente quer é o valor "list" que está dentro do state, e não da função setState, o que pode ser corrigido trocando esta linha por:

> const list = this.state.list.filter(u => u.id !== user.id)